# Laravel: Validate not certain column value found on row on table

Tags: laravel

I have the following validation rules:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|max:255|email',
            'role' => 'required|exists:roles,id',
        ];
    }
```

It's for invited users to an account. The performing user has to select a specific role and I'm validating whether that role is found on the database table.

However, i'd also like to validate that they didn't choose a specific role - "Owner". Only one "Owner" is allowed per account.

In addition to checking a column value on a table, can I also create the rule explained above?

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules) to check whether there is only one "Owner" on an account.

**Example:**

```php
Validator::extend('foo', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return $value == 'foo';
});
```